# How to fetch user endpoint with required Id or Key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I want to fetch a user endpoint from an API but I'm required to use an Id. I fetched the API manually but I'm having errors of uncaught in promise. Below is the error message and the code base. This is given to me to use alongside with the API "8wdkcw05bdEa47R"

```
VM56:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

```
export async function getUsers() {

    try {

        const response = await fetch('https://cornie-assessment.herokuapp.com/api-doc')

        return response.json()

    } catch (err) {

        console.log(err);

    }
}
```

Comment: That URL is, as the path suggests, for the _documentation_ of the API. Did you try _reading_ it?

Comment: `const response = await fetch('https://cornie-assessment.herokuapp.com/users/8wdkcw05bdEa47R')`

Comment: As the error suggests you are getting html back instead of json. You are trying to hit the wrong endpoint. Go the the url that you are trying to fetch just in your browser `https://cornie-assessment.herokuapp.com/api-doc` you can see it is not returning json but an html page. It is in fact the documentation page so you should read it.

Comment: by the way not sure if this thing is actually production or not but you may want to remove your url as it appears this api is not protected and anyone can run it